# Print specific range of lines with condition in python/bash

Tags: python, bash, shell, scripting, text-processing

This is the sample code

```
    DEBUG: extra
    DEBUG:Fri Dec  7 06:48:47 2018:16920:QOP: final output is test testtset
    output output
    output
    DEBUG: extra extra
    DEBUG: extra
```

My code is full of such blocks and I want to fetch all the outputs from "final output is" to the last output statement for all blocks.

Expected output:

```
 test testtset
    output output
    output
```

My code:

```
stream=open("debuglog.txt","r")
lines=stream.readlines()

for i in lines:
        if ("final output is" in i):
                print lines[lines.index(i)]
```

Currently my code only print the line which has text "final output is" but I want it to print full output till the next "DEBUG:"

Comment: What does your current attempt look like?

Comment: Please do mention the expected output in your post @Fullmetal and let us know then.

Comment: @Shayn I've posted my current attempt.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 I've already mentioned the expected output.

Comment: @Fullmetal Does my answer help? Sorry to have to say here but it's been a day and no activity.

Comment: @Jachdich Yes it works for the example. Thanks

Comment: Would `grep -A2 "final output is" log.txt` work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
stream=open("debuglog.txt","r")
lines=stream.readlines()

keep_line = False
for i in lines:
    if "DEBUG:" in i:
        keep_line = False
    if "final output is" in i:
        keep_line = True
    if keep_line:
        print(i)
```

It basically loops through each line after "final output is" until it finds another "DEBUG:".

Hope this helps.

Comment: Probably not the most pythonic way... It works for the example though.